# Perform a KMO test with some zero integers in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I want to perform a factor analysis with a data frame that contains some zero integers. A `head(df[1:10,1:20])` is shown below:

```
 library(corrplot)
 library(psych)
 library("psych")
 library(ggplot2)
 library(car)

 df <- read.csv('salvia.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ',')

 head(df[1:5,1:5])

Output:

able about actually again almost
1    2     2        0     8      
2    0     2        2     2      
3    0     1        0     0      
4    2     5        5     3      
5    0     3        0     2
```

As you see there are some zero values, but they are important for my research. When I apply the KMO function, the ouptut is as follows (just a snippet):

```
KMO(df)

Output:
able about actually again almost 
NA    NA     NA        NA     NA     

Warning message:
In cov2cor(Q) : diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful
```

I've tried to use

```
df[1:256] <- lapply(df[1:256], as.numeric)
```

but since it's already a numeric class, it didn't have any effect on the result. Please, how could I preserve the zeros for the tests? I've entered this same data frame into SPSS and it worked perfectly, but I want to perform all my analysis in R.

Comment: Can you please provide the full dataframe `df`? Based on the warning message from `KMO()` it seems like there are missing values. You might need to remove those missing values first. `as.numeric` will not remove missing values.

Comment: Type `help(KOM)`. The argument `r` requires "a correlation matrix or a data matrix (correlations will be found)".

Comment: @Harrison Jones, hello. I used the `complete.cases()` function and it returned FALSE for na values. When I try `sum(is.na(df))`, it returns 413. But when I try `na.omit(df)`, the problem remains the same. I'm afraid I can't provide the full dataframe here, since it's huge.

Comment: @Harrison Jones, as you can see in the output, all values return as NA. But they are there. Really weird.

Comment: Without the full data frame I can't reproduce the result.

Comment: @Harrison Jones, can I send the df to you by e-mail?

Comment: Is it too big for using `dput()`? I would try `dput()` first.

Comment: @HarrisonJones, when I applied the `dput()`, the output returned a weird last variable X, full of NAs. Curiously, I didn't find this variable in the original csv file. Anyway, I removed it in my code and the KMO worked! Thank you very much for your help!